# Symfony Messaging Bundle choices

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to figure out how to map database fields to a symnfony form choices.  The form is using the friends of symfony bundles, and this is my first symfony project (more of a Laravel/ CI person).

I am needing to populate a form choices based on fields in the database, problem is, I have no idea where in this project is the enity manager for the Doctrine ORM (its a really unorganized file structure), and I can't figure out how to just run a native query to test till I can figure that out.

The project uses the Message Bundle , Form Models / Handlers / Types etc.  I have the form being generated correctly, I just need to figure out where to put the data and how to do it.

So far I have this:

```
<?php

namespace Application\FOS\MessageBundle\FormType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use NeaceLukens\Bundle\Entity\File;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
// use NeaceLukens\Bundle\Entity\FileCollection;
use FOS\MessageBundle\FormModel\NewThreadMessage;

class NewThreadMessageBulkFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      // $choices = $this->getGroups();
        $builder
            ->add(
                'recipient', 'choice', array(
                'empty_value' => false,
                'multiple'=>true,
                'choices'=>array('1'=>'test1', '2'=>'test2', '3'=>'test3'),
                'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'), 
                )
            )
            ->add('subject', 'text', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('body', 'textarea', array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')));

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'intention'  => 'message'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fos_message_new_thread';
    }

    public function getGroups(){
        // build the mapping here? 
        /*
        $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()
                   ->getConnection()
                   ->prepare('SELECT t.id, t.name FROM fos_user_group');
      $r = $stmt->execute();
    return $r; */ 
    }
}
```

The function called getGroups errors out.  I get an error message that states the following:

Call to undefined Method Application\FOS\MessageBunde\FormType\NewThreadMessageBulkFormType::getEntityManager() in ....... line 63

Answer (score 0):

When you want a choice field to be populated with values from database, you should use "entity" filed type described here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: I figured as much, but the issue is that the choices aren't all contained in one entity, I need to query multiple tables, and then have those options in an array for the choices menu.  either way, that function above still fails and I can't figure out why

Comment: it fails because `$this->getEntityManager()` refers to function that is not defined. Did you just copy this call from base controller? If you need EntityManager in your type class, you can make your form a service and inject EntityManager to it. Another option is to compile your choices array in your controller, or somewhere else and pass it into your form using $options array.